# How do I add a custom view+controller to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.11

In Rails, when you generate a scaffold, it creates index, show, edit, and new views for it, as well as a host of methods in the associated controller.  How do I add my own view to the model?

For my Events model, I'd like to add /events/past to display all events that have already happened.  When I just add

```
def past
end
```

to `events_controller` and `create /views/events/past.html.erb`, then go to site.com/events/past, it looks for an event with the ID "past".

If I add `map.match '/events/past' => 'events#past'` to `routes.rb`, it says I must specify the controller.

If that's changed to `map.match '/events/past' => 'events#past', :controller => :events`, I'm back with the same "Couldn't find Event with ID=past" error.

Thanks for helping out someone who's new to Rails!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is the old Rails, I believe you must use:

```
map.match 'events/past', :controller => "events", :action => "past"
```

Comment: That worked - thank you.  For anyone else who has this problem, that line needs to go _before_ all of the `map.resources` lines because of priority.

Comment: No problem. You might also want to check out [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what your missing is the :on => :collection bit. Then I bet the order isn't important.